# Save image and text offline in android?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview

I have multiple activities which consists of listviews with image and text fetched from the server. I need them to be available in when user is offline just like what facebook. I am trying to figure out the best possible way to achieve that?

I currently have 3 approaches in my mind:

1. Save image as cache and text in shared preference or sqlite and display. But in this case mapping will be  difficult.
2. Save both image and text in SQLITE and display.
3. Save the images in SD card and display from there.

Which approach should I choose. Or is there any other solution to it?

Comment: As per my aspect saved all the text information into `SQLite` and saved all the images into private dir `(/data/data/yourPackage/Myfolder/images)`. and link the `Name` or `Id` of image to text data in `SQLite`

Comment: What if the user deletes the folder , then whole of the images will be downloaded again which will result in spending extra data connect plus downloading images takes time rather than getting the bitmap from URL

Comment: Wooohhh!! Ya that's right the folder that you create is `Private(/data/data/yourPackage/Myfolder/images)` so nobody can see. No one can touch expecting you. Now if you download this images in `SDCard` then def a chance to delete this `Dir` from `SDCard` by any user.  `(Seems like in iPhone (Jel break))`